# How to replace a tag with another tag in xml using xsl

Tags: xslt

My xml file looks like below.

```
<rule>  
  <name>86</name>
  <ruleId>100</ruleId>
  <ruleVersion>1.0</ruleVersion>
  <brlVersion>1.0</brlVersion>
</rule>
```

I need to replace name with brlName and i need to add another tag as drlName.The output should looks like below.

```
<rule>  
  <brlName>86</brlName>
  <ruleId>100</ruleId>
  <ruleVersion>1.0</ruleVersion>
  <brlVersion>1.0</brlVersion>
  <drlName>86_1.0</drlName>
</rule>
```

Please help me with corresponding xsl to get desired output.
Appreciated your help!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- using and overriding the identity rule/template.

Comment: Why some people ask questions and, after receiving, let me say, good answers, do not provide any feedback? This is very irritating sometime.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, empo.

Answer (score 6):

This is the typical task for the identity transform (the first template rule in the transform below). Just two overrides (the last two rules).

---

**XSLT 1.0** tested under **Saxon 6.5.5**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <brlName><xsl:value-of select="."/></brlName>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="brlVersion">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <drlName><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::name"/>_1.0</drlName>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  <brlName><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></brlName>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[last()]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   <drlName>86_1.0</drlName>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<rule>
    <name>86</name>
    <ruleId>100</ruleId>
    <ruleVersion>1.0</ruleVersion>
    <brlVersion>1.0</brlVersion>
</rule>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<rule>
   <brlName>86</brlName>
   <ruleId>100</ruleId>
   <ruleVersion>1.0</ruleVersion>
   <brlVersion>1.0</brlVersion>
   <drlName>86_1.0</drlName>
</rule>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using and overriding the identity rule/template -- the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern.
2. Override on any element named `name` and creating an element named `brlName` (rename).
3. Override on the last last element child of the top element. Calling the identity rule by name for this node (copying) and then creating an element named `drlName` with a specific text-node child as per the requirements.

**Using and overriding the identity rule/template is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern. You can learn more about it [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.