# get text and element nodes children of node using xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a tag who contains tags and text inside it.

```
<p>

Hello world <xref rid='1234'>1234</xref> this is a new world starting
<xref rid="5678">5678</xref>
finishing the new world

</p>
```

I 'm going to transform it using xslt and in the output i need to replace the `<xref>` for `<a>` and the the text should has the same format.

```
<p>

Hello world <a href='1234'>1234</a> this is a new world starting
<a href="5678">5678</a>
finishing the new world

</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a tag with another tag in xml using xsl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112874/how-to-replace-a-tag-with-another-tag-in-xml-using-xsl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach to this kind of thing in XSLT is an *identity template* to copy everything verbatim from input to output, which you then override with specific templates when you want to change something.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!-- identity template to copy everything as-is unless overridden -->
  <xsl:template match="*@|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace xref with a -->
  <xsl:template match="xref">
    <a><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></a>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace rid with href -->
  <xsl:template match="xref/@rid">
    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could combine the two "specific" templates into one if you know that every `xref` element will definitely have a `rid` attribute.

Note that no XSLT-based solution will be able to preserve the fact that some of your input elements used single quotes for attributes and others used double quotes, because this information isn't available in the XPath data model (both forms are completely equivalent as far as an XML parser is concerned).  It is likely that the XSLT processor will always use one or the other for all elements it outputs regardless of what the input element looked like.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is quite simple (only two templates):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="xref">
   <a href="{@rid}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<p>

Hello world <xref rid='1234'>1234</xref> this is a new world starting
<xref rid="5678">5678</xref>
finishing the new world

</p>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<p>

Hello world <a href="1234">1234</a> this is a new world starting
<a href="5678">5678</a>
finishing the new world

</p>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies every node for which it is selected for execution, "as-is".
2. Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute Value Templates) eliminates the need for `xsl:attribute`